# How to read a property of an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, anonymous-types, jsonresult

I have a method that returns

```
return new  System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult()
{                     
    Data = new
    {
        Status = "OK", 
    }
}
```

I need to write a unit test where I need to verify that `jsonResult.Data.status= "OK"`.

How do I read the status property?

Update:
I tried the [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestingAssemblyName")], but that didn't help. I kept getting the error {"'System.Web.Mvc.JsonResult' does not contain a definition for 'Status'"}

Besides I think I will prefer not modifying the code that I am testing.

So I took Jon's advice and used reflection.

```
        var type = jsonResult.Data.GetType();

        var pinfo = type.GetProperty("Status");

        string  statusValue = pinfo.GetValue(jsonResult.Data,null).ToString();

        Assert.AreEqual("OK", statusValue);
```

Comment: In a MS Unit Test or Javascript?

Comment: If you are doing this from C#, you could just use `dynamic` and let the dynamic binder take care of it.

Comment: gallio unit test. What I am trying is Assert.AreEqual("OK", jsonResult.Data.Status)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest approach would probably be to use dynamic typing:

```
dynamic foo = ret.Data;
Assert.AreEqual("OK", foo.status);
```

Note that you'll need to use `[InternalsVisibleTo]` in order to give your unit test assembly access to the anonymous type in your production assembly, as it will be generated with `internal` access.

Alternatively, just use reflection.

Answer (score 8):

`dynamic`:

```
dynamic testObject = YourMethodThatReturnsDynamicObject().Data;
Assert.AreEqual("OK", testObject.Status);
```

Comment: The expected value should be the first argument to `AreEqual`, and the actual value should be the second.

Comment: @JonSkeet .. there you go, although as I was typing it I just didn't think (sometimes intellisense goes a long way!).

Comment: @ AnonymousVoter: I appreciate the sympathy vote.. difficult to get any when you reply at the same time as Jon! :)